# How to search for a string in cell array in MATLAB by comparing it to another string?

Tags: string, matlab, compare

I have tried to use strcmp but I don't know how to look through the cell arrays and output only the cell arrays with that string.

For example str='Hello'

```
out=["Hello", "my", "name", "is" "sam"]
out=["What", "is", "you", "name"]
out=["Hello", "my", "name", "is" "John"]
```

My code is as follows

```
while ~feof(fid)
    line=fgetl(fid)
    if isempty(line)||strncmp(line, '%',1)||~ischar(line)
        continue
    end
    fprintf(line)
    out=regexp(line, '', 'split')
end
```

I want to add if(str=="Hello"), only print out those arrays

output

```
["Hello", "my", "name", "is" "sam"]
["Hello", "my", "name", "is" "John"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
if any(strcmp('Hello', out))
```

should be useful.

Answer (score 1):

use `ismember()` . For example, `out = {'Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'sam'};`, then `ismember(out, 'Hello')`  should be 1. You can check this discussion http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/284849

By the way, `out=["Hello", "my", "name", "is" "sam"]` is not a representation of a cell. It should be `out = {'Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'sam'}`

Comment: Thank you, these really helped, I got my code to work thanks. Do you know how to ignore the commas in an array. If there is a comma as part of the string, when I use ismember(out, 'Hello'), it doesn't print the sentences with Hello in them with a comma, also how to ignore capital letters

Comment: @Samira  you can use this function 'isstrprop' which is to determine whether string is of specified category to remove special chars like commas. Please check this link: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isstrprop.html